# Is it possible to accomplish the equivalent of a Flash-driven webcomic (zoom, drag, fade in, synced audio etc) using HTML5 techniques?

Tags: html, flash

## Bit of background

I've been producing a Flash-driven webcomic for three years now, incorporating some basic animation, a synced soundtrack and zoom-drag page viewing. The recent Flash-bashing, my desire to reach iHandhelds and my preference for open versus proprietary means that I want to make the move to HTML5 techniques this year. In the long-term, I think the writing's on the wall for Adobe's product, and I'm not entirely convinced that's a bad thing.

I'm relatively comfortably with both CSS and HTML, having worked a little in web design before. However, JavaScript is a foreign country to me, and I simply wanted to get some advice as to

1. whether what I want to achieve can be accomplished *consistently* across all browsers and
2. what the best techniques/approaches to the problem would be.

Any advice, even general principles, are very welcome. I've already sought out several HTML5 tutorials and introductions, which lead me to believe that the canvas element will be foundational to my plan; however while all the individual problems I face have been answered by many blogposts and guides, combining the various solutions into a single entity is something I'm not currently able to figure out, as I'm not certain of the limitations of the new HTML5 tags, or of best practice.

If I'm successful in achieving what I'm after, I'm going to post the full code online with an explanation of all the elements. Webcomics might not be a huge domain, but having a resource that did this would have made my life a lot easier - hopefully it'll help someone else in a similar position.

## What I'm after

Here's a diagram giving the basics of the design requirements. I'll explain the elements, and the desired extras, below.

[image]
(Perhaps the simplest way to demonstrate what I'm after would be for interested folks head over to [my website](http://www.basement-garden.co.uk) and see how my comic currently works. This isn't a plug - it would simply give the quickest insight.)

At core, I'm after a viewer that will:

- display text (SVG image) in a canvas element above an raster image the page's panel art
- both images should be zoom-and-draggable *in sync* but should ideally fade in separately, with the raster image coming first, followed by the SVG image

I'm guessing that the best way to accomplish this would be to layer two canvas elements one above the other using z-index, with the SVG file in the uppermost element. These could then be nested, as in the diagram, within a div element that would carry the zoom-drag function. Is this a reasonable approach, or are there more efficient options?

The next and previous buttons are self-explanatory. Would it best to have each page (bearing in mind some will involve animation and music) on a separate page, or to have all pages within a chapter on a single page, with the buttons making them visible progressively? I imagine this would have a great impact on loading speeds.

Finally, I'd like to have the viewer capable of displaying fullscreen if the reader desires. I imagine this could be accomplished by using Javascript to make the canvas elements and their surrounding div switch between different CSS giving a px-defined size and 100% height and width. Is this a good approach? Is it possible to apply the size change to the div element only and have the canvas elements automatically follow suit, possibly by defining their size via % in CSS?

### Desired extras

At various points in the comic I make use of basic animation techniques - simple movements of layered raster images across the viewing pane. This would be simple to accomplish, I imagine, using Javascript; am I correct in thinking that applying overflow:hidden to the wrapping div will prevent images larger than the viewing area from spilling outside the viewer area?

I also want to synchronise audio with some of these animations. I understand that synchronising canvas events with the audio would be the best way to do this on, permitting both to begin activity only upon page loading or next button click.

That's about everything. As said, any advice at *whatever* level would be greatly appreciated, even if it's 'yes' or 'no' to the various questions I've asked. At root, it would also be good to know if HTML5 is the best option for what I'm after or whether (with gritted teeth) I should stick to Flash for now and go after handhelds using Adobe AIR.

Comment: The writing is definitely on the wall for Flash so you'll want to move to HTML5. While I don't have specific suggestions, do believe you'll be able to pull this off using Canvas. After all, have you seen Quake running in Canvas? If that can be done, this can.

Comment: Try to be more specific. One question at a time. "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." - http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: Thanks both - David, that certainly puts things in perspective. Doesn't feel like such a mountain to climb. Pumbaa - fair point, I'll do some experimentation (it's been useful formulating the questions alone) and come back with some specifics. That said, if anyone's reading this, feel free to pitch in still.